# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]'

Tags: javascript, react-redux, next.js

Im really rellied about this issue, the case im trying to use a Material UI slider with redux.

here the slider component:

```
import { Slider } from '@material-ui/core'

const RangeSlider = ({handleRange, range}) => {
    
    const handleChange = (event, newValues) => {
        handleRange(newValues)
    }

    return (
        <Slider
            value={range}
            onChange={handleChange}
            valueLabelDisplay="auto"
            aria-labelledby="range-slider"
            min={0}
            max={100}
        />
    )
}

export default RangeSlider
```

here the filter component with redux logic:

```
import {
  Button,
  Typography as Tp,
  Select,
  MenuItem,
  Accordion,
  AccordionDetails,
  AccordionSummary,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { ExpandMore } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { RangeSlider } from "../components";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { filterUpdate } from "../redux/actions/filter";

const Filter = ({ models }) => {
  const [range, setRange] = useState([0,60]);
  const [modelSelected, setModelSelected] = useState("None");

  const handleRange = (newValue) => setRange(newValue);


  const handleModel = (event) => setModelSelected(event.target.value);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    let filterValues = {
      range,
      modelSelected,
    };
    dispatch(filterUpdate(filterValues));
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mt-3 ">
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMore />}
          aria-controls="panel-filter-content"
          id="panel-filter-header"
        >
          <Tp>Sort your search</Tp>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails className='d-flex align-items-center bg-light pb-3'>
          <div className='col-md-6'>
            <Tp className="mt-3">Pick up a price range</Tp>
            <RangeSlider handleRange={handleRange} range={range} />
          </div>
          <div className="col">
            <div className="col text-center pb-3">
              <Tp className="mt-3">Sort by model</Tp>
              <Select value={modelSelected} onChange={handleModel}>
                {models.map((model) => {
                  return (
                    <MenuItem key={model} value={model}>
                      {model}
                    </MenuItem>
                  );
                })}
              </Select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className=" col mt-5 text-center">
            <Button onClick={handleSubmit} variant="outlined" color="primary">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </div>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Filter;
```

Redux action logic:

```
import { createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import types from '../types'

export const filterUpdate = createAction(types.FILTER_UPDATE)
```

Here Reducer:

```
import { createReducer } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { filterUpdate } from '../actions/filter'

const reducer = createReducer({
    range: [0,60],
    model: 'None'
}, {
    [filterUpdate]: (state, action) => {
        state.range =  action.payload.range
        state.model = action.payload.modelSelected
    }
})

export default reducer
```

The error appear when i include the redux logic, when i tested with a console.log was fine, but with the dispatch, appear this error, also, its a random error because i can test to dispatch 2-3 times without error, but the next this error appear

What can i do to deal with that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sure, the code snippet can be reduced. Can you remove everything that works fine, leaving only the code that actually produces the error?

Comment: @adrihfly did you managed to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it fails to sort function inside the Slider.
That because the value that I passed into the component was a read-only (immutable).
So to avoid this error I should to pass in the value prop the copy of range array. Like this:

```
<Slider
    value={[...range]}
    // ....other props
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what is the problem, but your reducer is definitely wrong. You do:

```js
const reducer = createReducer({
    range: [0,60],
    model: 'None'
}, {
    [filterUpdate]: (state, action) => {
        state.range =  action.payload.range
        state.model = action.payload.modelSelected
    }
})
```

You probably meant to do this:

```js
const reducer = createReducer({
    range: [0,60],
    model: 'None'
}, {
    [filterUpdate]: (state, action) => ({
        range: action.payload.range,
        model: action.payload.modelSelected,
    })
})
```

Also you are not actually pulling state from redux store. You are importing `useSelector` and not calling it anywhere. Whatever `useState`  and `useDispatch` return are independent from each other in your code.